# Lengthy Query Optimization

Tags: query-optimization

is there any way to optimize this query currently execution time of this query is **585**
in this query only two table are use. one was Player detail table containing player info & other was corn_player_data contain scoring record

```
SELECT
  t.players_id,
  t.players_name,
  t.added_date,
  t.total_death  AS total_death,
  t.total_king   AS total_king,
  GROUP_CONCAT(t.week_number) AS week_number,
  GROUP_CONCAT(t.death) AS Death,
  GROUP_CONCAT(t.King) AS King
FROM (SELECT
        p.id             AS players_id,
        p.name           AS players_name,
        cpd.added_date   AS added_date,
        cpd4.total_death AS total_death,
        cpd5.total_king  AS total_king,
        WEEK(cpd.added_date) AS week_number,
        GROUP_CONCAT(cpd.added_date) AS NewDate,
        COUNT(cpd3.result) AS death,
        COUNT(cpd2.result) AS King
      FROM players AS p
        LEFT JOIN cron_players_data AS cpd
          ON cpd.player_id = p.id
        LEFT JOIN cron_players_data cpd2
          ON cpd2.player_id = p.id
            AND cpd2.result = 1
            AND cpd2.status = 1
            AND cpd2.added_date = cpd.added_date
        LEFT JOIN cron_players_data cpd3
          ON cpd3.player_id = p.id
            AND cpd3.result = 2
            AND cpd3.status = 1
            AND cpd3.added_date = cpd.added_date
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT
                     cron_p_d.player_id,
                     COUNT(cron_p_d.result) AS total_death
                   FROM cron_players_data cron_p_d
                   WHERE cron_p_d.result = 2
                       AND cron_p_d.status = 1
                   GROUP BY (cron_p_d.player_id)) AS cpd4
          ON cpd4.player_id = p.id
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT
                     cro_p_d.player_id,
                     COUNT(cro_p_d.result) AS total_king
                   FROM cron_players_data cro_p_d
                   WHERE cro_p_d.result = 1
                       AND cro_p_d.status = 1
                   GROUP BY (cro_p_d.player_id)) AS cpd5
          ON cpd5.player_id = p.id
      GROUP BY (p.id),WEEK(cpd.added_date)) AS t
GROUP BY t.players_id

TABLE              CREATE TABLE                                             
-----------------  ---------------------------------------------------------
cron_players_data  CREATE TABLE `cron_players_data` (                       
                     `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                  
                     `cat_id` BIGINT(30) DEFAULT '0',                       
                     `sub_cat_id` BIGINT(30) DEFAULT '0',                   
                     `team_id` BIGINT(30) DEFAULT '0',                      
                     `player_id` BIGINT(30) DEFAULT '0',                    
                     `status_team` VARCHAR(225) DEFAULT NULL,               
                     `result` BIGINT(30) DEFAULT '0',                       
                     `home` BIGINT(30) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0',                
                     `guest` BIGINT(30) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0',               
                     `mvp` BIGINT(30) DEFAULT '0',                          
                     `oscar` BIGINT(30) DEFAULT '0',                        
                     `wam` BIGINT(30) DEFAULT '0',                          
                     `crown` BIGINT(30) DEFAULT '0',                        
                     `kiss` BIGINT(30) DEFAULT '0',                         
                     `slap` BIGINT(30) DEFAULT '0',                         
                     `bomb` BIGINT(30) DEFAULT '0',                         
                     `status` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0',                       
                     `added_date` DATE DEFAULT NULL,                        
                     PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)                                    
                   ) ENGINE=MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=265 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8  

TABLE    CREATE TABLE                                                                              
-------  -----------------------------------------
players  CREATE TABLE `players` (                                                                  
           `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                                                   
           `cat_id` BIGINT(30) DEFAULT '0',                                                        
           `sub_cat_id` BIGINT(30) DEFAULT '0',                                                    
           `team_id` BIGINT(30) DEFAULT '0',                                                       
           `name` VARCHAR(225) DEFAULT NULL,                                                       
           `class_name` VARCHAR(225) DEFAULT NULL,                                                 
           `image` VARCHAR(225) DEFAULT NULL,                                                      
           `added_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
           PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)                                                                     
         ) ENGINE=MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=147 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

output will be like this

```
players_id  players_name    added_date  total_death total_king  week_number Death   King
81  Mario Chalmers  2012-06-08  6   7   23,24,25,26 2,3,1,0 0,2,4,1
82  Udonis Haslem   2012-06-09  2   7   23,24,25,26 0,1,0,1 1,1,4,1
83  James Jones 2012-06-09  10  3   23,24,25,26 0,7,3,0 1,0,1,1
84  Chris Bosch 2012-06-09  8   4   23,24,25,26 1,4,2,1 0,2,2,0
85  Dwayne Wade 2012-06-09  6   4   23,24,25,26 1,3,1,1 0,2,2,0
86  Eddie House 2012-06-09  5   4   23,24,25,26 0,3,2,0 1,1,1,1
87  Joel Anthony    2012-06-09  6   6   23,24,25,26 1,3,1,1 1,2,3,0
88  Mike Bibby  2012-06-08  5   9   23,24,25,26 0,3,1,1 2,3,4,0
89  Mike Miller 2012-06-09  7   8   23,24,25,26 1,4,1,1 1,2,4,1
90  Erick Dampier   2012-06-09  11  1   23,24,25,26 2,5,2,2 0,0,1,0
91  Lebron James    2012-06-09  7   4   23,24,25,26 1,4,1,1 0,2,2,0
92  Juwan Howard    2012-06-08  5   4   23,24,25,26 1,2,1,1 0,1,3,0
```

Comment: Adding tables structuctures, indexes involved, etc, and even a script to recreate and test, would be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using mysql or sqlserver? those create statments do not work on MSSQL. I guess you are using mySQL, not worked a lot with it but these post can help you.

[MySql BigInt(20) vs Int(20)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135804/types-in-mysql-bigint20-vs-int20-etcc)
[SQL Server BigInt or Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124631/sql-server-int-or-bigint-database-table-ids)

Basically (yet without testing) I guess the Bigint values are not worth as you have really small values on those columns. You are wasting lot of space and also indexes and everything related is also taking lot of it too. Try switching to the smallest numeric type that fits your cases (small int, tinyint?)